# How can I write mocks that capture method parameters and examine them later?

Tags: .net, mocking

I'm looking for a way to capture the actual parameter passed to method to examine it later. The idea being to get the passed parameter and then execute assertions against it.

For instance:

```
var foo = Mock<Foo>();
var service = Mock<IService>();
service.Expect(s => s.Create(foo));
service.Create(new Foo { Currency = "USD" });
Assert(foo.Object.Currency == "USD");
```

Or a bit more complex example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Title = "...", Description = "..." };
var bar = Mock.NewHook<Bar>();
var service = new Mock<IService>();
service.Expect(s => s.Create(bar));

new Controller(service.Object).Create(foo);

Assert(foo.Title == bar.Object.Title);
Assert(foo.Description == bar.Object.Description);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for something equivalent to Moq's Callback:

```
var foo = Mock<Foo>();
var service = Mock<IService>();
service.Setup(s => s.Create(foo.Object)).Callback((T foo) => Assert.AreEqual("USD", foo.Currency))
service.Object.Create(new Foo { Currency = "USD" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assert on the parameter passed to an object, it seems you're subjecting the wrong object to your test. Instead of asserting the parameters passed to a method, write a test for the calling class that asserts the correct parameters are passed.

Comment: I try to test that Controller.Create will create and pass correct object into IService.Create.

Answer (score 0):

See also section "Callbacks" in [Moq's Quickstart documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks):

```
// access invocation arguments
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((string s) => calls.Add(s));
```